# What is the best way to sell complete used LEGO sets?

Tags: shopping

I have some used Star Wars LEGO sets (one is discontinued and has been for a while), some Marvel/DC LEGO sets, and some miscellaneous sets. What is the best way to sell these?

Comment: Selling is easiest via either BrickLink.com, it's direct competitor BrickOwl.com, or EBay. The "lots of money" part is the biggest problem: unless you truly have rare/collectible sets, and they are complete with instructions, it is unlikely you will make a lot of money after shipping, time spent sorting/cleaning and of course the fees levied by the marketplace of your choice. But we can definitely give you a better answer if you post the set names and numbers here ..

Comment: Making lots of money takes lots of time.  Getting money soon usually means leaving some money on the table.  So since you probably don't get to have your cake and eat it too you need to decide on what is a higher priority and go from there.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that your sets are complete? You should verify that no pieces are lost, either by building the set or by checking LEGO's parts database (can do that on [Brickset.com](https://brickset.com/)). If pieces are missing, you may want to order these.

On [BrickPicker.com](http://www.brickpicker.com) you find current market values of sets, so you know what asking price to set. That site collects eBay price data regularly. Then select marketplaces; eBay is used a lot by LEGO investors and it has an international audience of buyers. When it's time to ship your items you need to take care packaging the sets properly. To some buyers the condition of the box will be of great importance.

As you can see there's a lot of work involved with LEGO selling, and if you want to make serious profits you need to get economies of scale in your business, not just selling one or two sets.

Comment: Plus, if you have no prior selling history on EBay, and you truly have an expensive/desirable set, people will be wary of ordering with you. You would have to sell some smaller, cheaper items first to build up a reputation as a reliable seller, which takes time.