# What is the best way to sell sealed LEGO sets?

Tags: shopping, star-wars

My kids have inherited a massive LEGO collection. 90%+ is in mint condition, still sealed. There are thousands of sealed boxes - currently kept in storage. There are plenty of open sets that the boys will keep, but the bulk we are looking to sell. What is the best way to do this? Any advice would be appreciated. A large amount of sets are Star Wars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to sell complete LEGO sets?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9339/what-is-the-best-way-to-sell-complete-lego-sets)

Comment: I vote to keep this one open, since TJM is asking mainly about new and sealed sets in perfect condition. This excludes all efforts to check for completeness etc.

Comment: I've edited both this question and the linked possible duplicate to make it clear that this question is for NIB sets and the other is for open sets.

Comment: That sounds good to me.  It seemed like a dupe at first glance, but it was challenging finding the other "one".

Answer (score 2):

If you really have that much (hundreds or more sets to move), you have some options:

Set up a Ebay store:
    Up front cost: None
    Profit: ~80% of net (Ebay takes a cut, Taxes, shipping materials)
    The slow burn option. You will eventually get rid of everything, but it will take some time, and many trips to the post office.

Go rent a table at a local Lego convention:
    Up front cost: probably a few hundred bucks
    Profit: After the booth /table cost, all the money is pretty much yours.
    This will get rid of stuff fast if you go to a sizable convention and you price reasonably. People buy a lot of lego at Lego conventions. You will have to plan this in advance, since tables might require being reserved months in advance.

Find a reliable Lego collector to sell it for you:
    I had a good friend who is an active member of the local Lego community do this for a family who acquired a huge vintage Lego collection. I think he took about a 20% cut and had most of it sold off in a few months. The upside of this approach is that you don't have to do anything but count the money you make. Make sure you get someone who knows what they are doing though. Older collectors are good choices, since they know a lot of the history of sets and themes.

I don't know how good sites liek Bricklink are for selling sets. It is a fantastic place to buy sell loose parts, but I don't know how quickly sets move there.