# Advice on selling a lot of Lego?

Tags: shopping

I have a bin of Lego with a bunch of $100+ sets. The bin contains 29lbs. of Lego. I want to sell them, how should I price them? There are sets like 7743 and such. They are in pristine condition. There might be other small objects in the bin, but I don't know what. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Sincerely,
Nathan

Comment: Please clarify your question with information regarding how you want to sell the sets, individually or in bulk.  "They are in pristine condition." for example. Are you referring to the sets or the pieces?

Answer (score 1):

Post an auction on ebay, and let the buyers determine the worth.  Include a lot of pictures of what is in the lot, so buyers know what they are getting.  If you go random, the most folks will pay is what it is worth with all low valued pieces. 

If you want to make more money, sort the Lego out, and see if you can complete sets.  For some sets the complete set will sell for more than the individual pieces, for other sets the individual pieces will sell for more. 

If you want to maximize profit do some research on sites like ebay, bricklink, brickowl and see what the parts you have are selling for.  If not, then just post it as you described it here, as an auction on eBay, and see if anyone bids.

Answer (score 1):

Your question could use some clarity. "Bin of Lego" and "pristine condition" seem to contradict itself. You mention the weight, which is standard for selling in bulk, but then ask, "How do I price them?" as if selling sets individually. If the sets are complete they are going to be worth more, especially if the minifigures are with them. Inclusion of instruction manuals and boxes also can add significant value. How much depends on the condition of the pieces, minifigures, instructions, the box and if the set is popular/desired.

You can look them up on Ebay to give you an idea of the current going rate, or use Bricklink. Enter the set number and navigate to its page where you will see a "Price Guide" option on the lower right:

[image]

It will take you to a page showing how much they have been selling for, and how much they are currently selling for:

[image]

You really should have searched for this topic before posting, there are a lot of answers available to very similar questions:

[How should I arrange LEGO to sell per pound?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8534/how-should-i-arrange-lego-to-sell-per-pound)
[What is the easiest way to sell Lego sets for a good price?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4422/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-sell-lego-sets-for-a-good-price)
[Value/Where to sell my old Lego collection](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6611/value-where-to-sell-my-old-lego-collection)
[How to sell a large amount of Lego](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9716/how-to-sell-a-large-amount-of-lego)
[What is the best way to sell complete used LEGO sets?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9339/what-is-the-best-way-to-sell-complete-used-lego-sets)
[Selling bulk LEGO](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9095/selling-bulk-lego)

The list goes on...
https://bricks.stackexchange.com/search?q=sell+lego