# Determining the age and value of old NIB Lego sets

Tags: sets, value

I have several old Lego sets, new in box.  Maybe 20 years old or more.  How to determine the age and value of these old Lego sets?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going to Bricklink and entering the set numbers in.  You will find the information on the sets you have and, if it isn't extremely rare, a price guide with information on how much the set has sold for in the past and how much it's currently selling for.

Bricklink: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page

There is a lot of information on this site that you may find useful, here is a link to one of the more recent inquiries with an answer and more information.

[Advice on selling a lot of Lego?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/11604/advice-on-selling-a-lot-of-lego/11606#11606)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using BrickLink for checking resale values is to use [BrickPicker](https://www.brickpicker.com). BrickPicker bases its “current value” on Sold prices from EBay, which sees larger traffic than BrickLink. You do need to count on paying for shipping, and paying 13% of the revenue (including shipping costs) to EBay and Paypal. BrickLink charges significantly less, and shipping is paid for by the buyer.

If you have a large list of LEGO sets you are seeking to valuate, BrickPicker offers a bulk lot evaluation tool which saves you time.

Comment: Ebay definitely gets more overall traffic than bricklink, but do we have any evidence that ebay moves more LEGO's than bricklink?  I've used ebay for years, but I'd rather get LEGO stuff from bricklink given the community and the reliability.  I know that I shouldn't generalize from myself too often, but I'd still be surprised if ebay sold more than bricklink.

Comment: Fair point, but Bricklink is only known in AFOL circles, while EBay is globally known. Many people use Amazon and EBay during the Holiday season, and LEGO sells quite fast during those months. That’s what I was hinting at.

Comment: I would wager that Bricklink has more Lego transactions, but because of the frequency of bulk sales, Ebay sells more pieces.  Then you slipped Amazon in there for some reason... ?  ;)